# Dialog is not opening up for the second time (after closing) when using the Dynamic data

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts

I am writing a dialog popup to perform some task through it. Popup is opening up fine for the first time but its not showing up for the second click. Here is the code I am using to open the popup, Can you please let me know whats wrong here?

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
   $( "#ALERT_POPUP" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false, 
      height:400, 
      width:900, 
      modal:true,    
      show: 'slide', 
      hide: 'slide',
      close: function(ev, ui) {$(this).remove();}
   });
});

$( "#alertPopup").click(function() { 
   $.ajax({
url: "alertAction.do?reqCode=alertSearch",
   success: function(returnedData){
         $('#ALERT_POPUP').empty().append(returnedData).dialog('open');
         return false;
      } 
   }); 
});
```

Question: Also i Want to multiple operation on dialog single window. Can some one give me some pointer to submit the dialog form multiple time without going to parent window? Please help!!!

Comment: use firebug and please post the error that you get

Comment: Error: $("#ALERT_POPUP").empty().append(returnedData).dialog is not a function
Source File: http://localhost:9080/MedPrimeEMRProj/mp.do?reqCode=login#
Line: 317

Comment: Same thing works fine for the first time but for next click (after closing the dialog) it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dialog's close event $(this).remove() means that you remove the "#ALERT_POPUP" div from the DOM, so the second time you want to open the dialog, it does not exist. There's no need for the close event I think.

**EDIT**

A working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready( function() {
           $( "#ALERT_POPUP" ).dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              height:400,
              width:900,
              modal:true,
              show: 'slide',
              hide: 'slide'
           });

           $("#alertPopup").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.html",
                    success: function(returnedData){
                        $('#ALERT_POPUP').empty().append(returnedData).dialog('open');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="ALERT_POPUP"></div>

    <button id="alertPopup">Click!</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Note that the close event is removed and the "#alertPopup" click init is inside the $(document).ready function.

Comment: Even after removing close event or closing it by .dialog('close') it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for spending time for this question... I have tried it and it worked... (With some  changes)
$(document).ready( function() { 
 var dialog = $( "#ALERT_POPUP" );
   dialog.dialog({
      autoOpen: false, 
      height:400, 
      width:900, 
      modal:true,    
      show: 'slide', 
      hide: 'slide'
   });

 $( "#alertPopup").click(function() { 
    $.ajax({
   url: "alertAction.do?reqCode=alertSearch",
      success: function(returnedData){
           dialog.empty().append(returnedData).dialog('open');
           return false;
        } 
    }); 
 });
});